# Format result for requesting all data

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-eloquent-resource

I have my controller with `index()` and `show()`.

```
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \App\Http\Resources\MyRessource
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //???
    }


    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Test  $test
     * @return \App\Http\Resources\TestRessource
     */
    public function show(Test $test)
    {
        return new \App\Http\Resources\TestRessource($test);
    }
}
```

In my resource the `show()` has the format I want for return, so the result for http://127.0.0.1/Test/1 is the ID 1 with the formatted JSON.

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "ref": "0103573026466442101007175850",
        "tax": null,
        "date_in": "2021-10-08T12:37:05.000000Z",
        "date_out": "2021-10-11T08:02:17.000000Z"
    }
}
```

I want the `index()` to return the same way by using my resource.
When I do `index()` on http://127.0.0.1/Test, it returns all my data but not in the formatted JSON that I want.

Resource code:

```
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|\JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "ref" => $this->ref,
            "tax" => $this->tax,
            "date_in" => $this->date_in,
            "date_out" => $this->date_out
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `index()` do as in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections).

```
return TestRessource::collection(Test::all());
```

Comment: Thank you it's work but when I have a lot of data, it's very, very slow. More than 2 minutes. Is it possible to paginate this result?

Comment: I think I found a solution: ```return TestRessource::collection(Test::query()->paginate(20));```

Comment: @Franck you can just do do `Test::paginate(20)`.